# Load GUI from a Glade with GtkSourceView in PyGObject

Tags: python, glade, pygobject, gtksourceview

I'm trying to use a Glade file that has a GtkSourceView widget in PyGObject. I've wrote a little guide on how to start using the new GtkSourceView 3.0 in Glade: http://cjenkins.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/use-gtksourceview-widget-in-glade/

The problem is when I want to load that Glade from PyGObject:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GtkSource
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

WHERE_AM_I = abspath(dirname(__file__))

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.glade_file = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'test.glade')
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        gui = MyApp()
        Gtk.main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

When I run that file I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    gui = MyApp()
  File "test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Invalid object type `GtkSourceView'
```

The Glade file (test.glade) is just a window with a GtkSourceView widget in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtksourceview 3.0 -->
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkSourceView" id="gtksourceview1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="has_tooltip">True</property>
        <property name="left_margin">2</property>
        <property name="right_margin">2</property>
        <property name="tab_width">4</property>
        <property name="auto_indent">True</property>
        <property name="indent_on_tab">False</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

An how to solve this is out of my knowledge right now. I suppose I need to register some type before calling add_from_file(), not? Any idea is welcome.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu Precise 12.04
- Glade 3.12.0
- libgtksourceview 3.0
- Gtk+ 3.0

Kind regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out :D I just needed to register the new type in GObject before calling **add_from_file()** as I suspected. Just needed to add GObject in the imports from gi.repository and call **type_register()** like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GtkSource, GObject
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

WHERE_AM_I = abspath(dirname(__file__))

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.glade_file = join(WHERE_AM_I, 'test.glade')
        GObject.type_register(GtkSource.View)
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        gui = MyApp()
        Gtk.main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

I'll update the page with this info.

Kind regards